# How to represent in Linear Programming (equations)?

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose $i$ varies from $0$ to $4$.

$A_i$, $S_i$, $E_i$ are binary variables.

Now, if $S_1=1$ and $E_3=1$, then how to make $A_1=A_2=A_3=1$ and $A_0=A_4=0$ using linear equations?

Comment: Those... are linear equations? If they don't work for you, can you clarify what more you want from them?

Comment: How to represent them in linear equation? `sum of (Ai)=3` but this does not guarantee `A4` will be `0`...

Comment: What I mean is, $A_0 = 0$ and $A_1 = 1$ and $A_2 = 1$ and so on are all linear equations already.

Comment: S[1]=1. E[3]=1, Then for which linear equation(s) make A[1to3]=1.
3E[3]-1xS[1]+1=3, terms of A[i] will be 1. so sum of A[i]=3; S[1]=A[1] and E[1]=A[1] is also okay. But to forcefully make all middle A[i] =1?

Comment: If the $A$ are known,what's the point including them in the equations ? They aren't unknowns, they are constants.

Comment: "for all `i` between `Si` and `Ei` on `Ai`": what the hell does that mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a constraint $$A_i = \sum_{j \le i} S_j - \sum_{j < i} E_j$$ for each value of $i$ then I think that does what you want.

Assuming there is some starting index $a$ for which $S_a = 1$ and some ending index $b$ for which $E_b = 1$, and all other $S$ and $E$ variables are $0$, the first sum in this constraint will be $1$ if $i \ge a$, and the second sum will be $1$ if $i > b$. So we'll have $0-0$ for $i<a$, $1-0$ for $a \le i \le b$, and $1-1$ for $i>b$.

You probably also want the constraints $$\sum_{i=0}^n S_i = \sum_{i=0}^n E_i = 1,$$ so that there's exactly one starting index and exactly one ending index.

Comment: absolutely. You are a genius. My thinking stuck to some other directions.